# Отредактировать значения записей DataFrame содержащие * и () и разделить колонку

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas

Есть список персон с пометками

| Person |
| --- |
| Jake Myers |
| C.J. Coles (M) |
| Kyle Willington * |
| Matthew Smith |
| Peter Potter (J) * |

на выходе нужны имена отдельно, опции отдельно (примерно так)

| Person | Status | Online |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jake Myers |  |  |
| C.J. Coles | M |  |
| Kyle Willington |  | yes |
| Matthew Smith |  |  |
| Peter Potter | J | yes |

Формат известен без всяких Nan и 0

- Опция 1: J,M или K
- Опция 2: есть * или нет
- Могут сочетаться.

Пробовал начать разбирать со звездочек через `np where` -

```py
df['Status'] = np.where(df.Person.str[2:] != " *", 1,0)
```

по кондициям не совсем пролезает, на соседних столбцах работает...

Опция 1 прихватывает все заглавные буквы из-за скобок. Опция 2 вообще все. Заход через `iloc` тоже помог не сильно.

Иногда спасал `split` в несколько проходов (на известном формате данных), но не в этом случае.

Решается ли без `import re` и как правильно составить условия, если нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Person':['Jake Myers', 'C.J. Coles (M)', 'Kyle Willington *', 'Matthew Smith', 'Peter Potter (J) *']})

rx = r'^(.*?)(?:\s*\(([^()]+)\)|)\s*(\*?)$'
df[['Person','Status','Online']] = df['Person'].str.extract(rx)
df['Status'] = df['Status'].fillna("")
df["Online"] = df["Online"].replace({"*": "yes"})
```

Результат:

```py
>>> df
            Person Status Online
0       Jake Myers              
1       C.J. Coles      M       
2  Kyle Willington           yes
3    Matthew Smith              
4     Peter Potter      J    yes
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/W5C7Zc/1):

- `^` - начало строки
- `(.*?)` - Подмаска 1: ноль и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `(?:\s*\(([^()]+)\)|)` - незахватывающая подмаска, находит ноль и более пробельных символов, `(`, один и более отличных от `(` и `)` символов (захватываемые в подмаску 2), `)`
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `(\*?)` - Подмаска 3: необязательный символ `*`
- `$` - конец строки.

`df['Status'].fillna("")` заменяет все `NaN` в столбце `Status` на пустую строку, а `df["Online"].replace({"*": "yes"})` заменяет все `*` в столбце `Online` на значение `yes`.

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: Разобрался как это сделать. Благодарю.